# Can't gem install json -v '1.7.3'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I get the following output when trying to install json gem on lion:

> gem install json -v '1.7.3' Building native extensions.  This could
>   take a while... ERROR:  Error installing json:    ERROR: Failed to build
>   gem native extension.
>
> /Users/victorstan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb creating Makefile
>
> make compiling parser.c make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or
>   directory make: *** [parser.o] Error 1

Comment: Looks like you're on OSX. Did you recently install or upgrade xcode? mkmf generated a Makefile with a bad compiler, so you may have some bad symlinks hanging around still. This is definitely a system-level issue. You can probably resolve it with a symlink, but it's worth your time to investigate just what is going on to cause this issue.

Comment: I wish I knew how to investigate, how do I know what the bad symlinks are?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `which gcc` and create a symlink to it in /usr/bin/gcc-4.2. e.g.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Comment: I had to also do `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.2`